# android aapt error:no layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf

Tags: android, android-resources, aapt

when i use aapt comandline to generate .R file for a new created android project,it shows that

`No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'com.test.androidpack'`

so,how to contain constraint-layout in aapt command line?

my command line is as below:

`aapt package -f ^
-M C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\AndoidPack\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml ^
-I D:\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar ^
-S C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\AndoidPack\app\src\main\res ^
-J gen ^
-m`

and I tried add `-I xxxx\constraint-layout-1.1.1.aar`,`-j constraint-layout-1.1.1.aar`,all failed

Answer (score 7):

The attribute "layout_constraintHorizontal_bias" is for the ConstraintLayout. But, in your layout file, there's a LinearLayout.

Try replacing that LinearLayout with a ConstraintLayout.

You may need to also add

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

to the dependencies block in your build.gradle file for this app module.

and then clean and invalidate the project it works like charm

Answer (score 2):

add to your app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    ...
}
```